# Protecting Excel Worksheet Data From Savvy User

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a excel application that will be distributed to my associates.  Based permissions I need to disable access to certain sheets and features. I've been able to protect and hide sheets but a savvy user is able to iterate over hidden worksheets internally or externally to expose data. I need to stop that.

**Here's the process:**

When the workbook opens a query to remote database is made to return set of user permissions. Then those permissions are printed to worksheet called "PERMISSIONS".

[image]

This code below iterates over worksheet permissions to find a particular setting by passing in column name.

```
CheckPerm "Timesheet"

Public Function CheckPerm(nPermColTarget As String) As Boolean
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

    Counter = 3
      Do Until Sheet7.Cells(Counter, 1).Value = Associate_Name
        Counter = Counter + 1
      Loop
    y = Counter

    Counter = 2
      Do Until Sheet7.Cells(2, Counter).Value = nPermColTarget
        Counter = Counter + 1
      Loop
    x = Counter

   If Sheet7.Cells(y, x).Value = "ON" Then
      CheckPerm = True
      GrntDenySheetAccess nPermColTarget, y, x, CheckPerm
   Else
   ' "OFF"
      CheckPerm = False
      GrntDenySheetAccess nPermColTarget, y, x, CheckPerm
   End If
End Function


Private Sub GrntDenySheetAccess(nPermColTarget As String, y As Integer, _ 
x As Integer, CheckPerm As Boolean)

Select Case nPermColTarget

   ' Sheet1
    Case "Timesheet"

       If CheckPerm = True Then
          Sheet1.Unprotect "pass"
          Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetVisible
       End If

       If CheckPerm = False Then
          Sheet1.Protect "pass"
          Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
       End If

 End Select

End Sub
```

But even though sheet1 is hidden and protected, I can still iterate over hidden sheet1's content to access info. Anyway to stop that?

Thanks

Comment: In short, not that I know of.  If you really want/need tight security, Excel is not the application you should be using.

Comment: @Tim I agree, it's was a constraint I was given though. Thanks.

Comment: If your constraint is Microsoft Office in general, consider using an Access DB frontend and convert it to an accde.  It's relatively locked down.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any ways to safely protect access to anything in an Excel workbook. Passwords are much harder to crack in Excel versions 2007 and onward, but a user can simply save the workbook as a `.xls` file and then it becomes easy to crack.

The best you can do is to make it a little tougher for somebody to get into. Password protect your file, and set any sheets that you don't want them to get to to `xlSheetVeryHidden`, which prevents users from unhiding the sheets through the Excel user interface.

The commenters under your question are correct. If you want a secure application, Excel isn't the answer.

[image]

Having said that, if you enforce security in the database layer, Excel makes a great UI. Just make sure you don't store or retrieve data that the user shouldn't see.

Comment: I believe you are correct. Pretty sad that Microsoft has had about 25 years to get this right, and they still haven't...

Comment: Thanks, all roads lead to the conclusion I don't want to admit. I'm going to push for a web based application with server side scripting to protect data.

Comment: Take a look at the note I added to the end of my answer. It may give you an option to re-platforming.

Comment: @HeadofCatering I explore this idea. Thanks.